# Creating internal multiplayer name prompt

Tags: android, flash, actionscript

So I'm pretty lost right now.. Google hasn't helped in this aspect much..

I'm creating an Android app/game..

I'm working with Flash CS6, and Actionscript 3.0

What I'm trying to do is create a prompt that asks how many players will be playing, and then have them input their names after selecting the amount of players..

After that I need the names to display one after another in order at the top of the screen everytime the game changes frame.

Also, the button that changes frames generates random frames. (Already have the generate random frame code)

The perfect example of what i'm trying to do is a game on the Google Play app store called "A Drinking Game"

The multiplayer prompts are exactly what I need..

Please help me out here, or at least point me in the right direction.. You guys have helped me out on here so much already..Thank you so much in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're certainly going to need some user interface components. There are a number of third-party options you could explore or you could get them from the components menu in the Flash IDE. You'll probably want a [`NumericStepper`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa5.html) to capture the number of players and, based on the value the user enters in the stepper, a number of [`TextInput`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/ActionScript/3.0_UsingComponentsAS3/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118a9c65b32-7fa5.html) components to capture the names of the players.

Your list of players should be stored in an [`Array`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/Array.html) which you will need to loop through on each frame, creating and adding to the stage a `TextField` for each element. It's not 100% clear from your question, but it sounds like there may need to be a delay between the display of each player's name. If this is the case, you would need to explore the ActionScript 3.0 [`Timer`](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/Timer.html) class.

Comment: Thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction. I definitely needed some terms to get myself started on this. You've been a great help. I'll come back when and if i have some more questions.

Comment: No problem. Good luck with your game.

Comment: I don't mean to bug you but I've been googling for hours and I'm just so lost. Would you have any sample code you may be able to give me to get me started? If it's too much to ask I understand, I've already taken a good amount of your time anyway.

Comment: I'm happy to help but, as you've guessed, I don't have the time to write the code for you (and that probably goes for the majority of people on here). What I would suggest is that you try to break the problem into smaller chunks, for example you could start by trying to implement a NumericStepper to capture the number of players, and, if you get stuck, come back with another more specific question. You can leave a comment here pointing to your new question and I'll certainly try to assist if I can.

Comment: I've actually decided to use a list component with different labels having numbers on them that will apply to how many inputText boxes come up for name input.. I'm just so stuck on the code .. When clicking on a number I want that amount of textInput boxes to come up one after another.. I know it's a lot of code, I'm still workin on it, feel free to help if you can.. Once again thanks so much for everything.